# To prove $\tan \phi_m + \sec \phi_m =(\tan \phi_1 + \sec \phi_1)^m $

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, induction

If $\phi_1, \phi_2, ... $ is a series of positive acute angles so that $\tan \phi_{m+1} = \tan \phi_m \sec \phi_1 + \sec \phi_m \tan \phi_1$ then prove that-
$$\tan \phi_{m+n} = \tan \phi_m \sec \phi_n + \sec \phi_m \tan \phi_n$$
$$\sec \phi_{m+n} = \sec \phi_m \sec \phi_n + \tan \phi_m \tan \phi_n$$
$$\tan \phi_m + \sec \phi_m =(\tan \phi_1 + \sec \phi_1)^m $$

Comment: I dont think $$\tan \phi_{m+n} = \tan \phi_m \sec \phi_n + \sec \phi_m \tan \phi_n$$ need to be proved,,, it is clearly given in the question itself

Comment: You posted the exact same question yesterday. Deleting and reposting is not the way to attract attention to a question. In the future, you should edit your question to improve its content. (Trivial edits to "bump" a question are inappropriate, however.) Your previous post did not provide any context about what you know about the problem or where you got stuck. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to your skill level, without wasting time telling you what you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t:=\text{arctanh}\big(\sin(\phi_1)\big)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  Observe that $$\sin(\phi_1)=\tanh(t)\,,\,\,\cos(\phi_1)=\text{sech}(t)\,,\,\,\tan(\phi_1)=\sinh(t)\,,\text{ and }\sec(\phi_1)=\cosh(t)\,.$$ It follows that $$\sin(\phi_2)=\tanh(2t)\,,\,\,\cos(\phi_2)=\text{sech}(2t)\,,\,\,\tan(\phi_2)=\sinh(2t)\,,\text{ and }\sec(\phi_2)=\cosh(2t)\,.$$  By induction, $$\sin(\phi_m)=\tanh(mt)\,,\,\,\cos(\phi_m)=\text{sech}(mt)\,,\,\,\tan(\phi_m)=\sinh(mt)\,,\text{ and }\sec(\phi_m)=\cosh(mt)\,,$$
for all $m=1,2,3,\ldots$.  That is,
$$\begin{align}\tan(\phi_{m+n})&=\sinh\big((m+n)t\big)\\&=\sinh(mt)\,\cosh(nt)+\cosh(mt)\,\sinh(nt)\\&=\tan(\phi_m)\,\sec(\phi_n)+\sec(\phi_m)\,\tan(\phi_n)\,,\end{align}$$
for each $m,n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Similarly,
$$\begin{align}\sec(\phi_{m+n})&=\cosh\big((m+n)t\big)\\&=\cosh(mt)\,\cosh(nt)+\sinh(mt)\,\sinh(nt)\\&=\sec(\phi_m)\,\sec(\phi_n)+\tan(\phi_m)\,\tan(\phi_n)\,,\end{align}$$
for each $m,n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Finally,
$$\begin{align}\tan(\phi_m)+\sec(\phi_m)&=\sinh(mt)+\cosh(mt)=\exp(mt)=\big(\exp(t)\big)^m\\&=\big(\sinh(t)+\cosh(t)\big)^m=\big(\tan(\phi_1)+\sec(\phi_1)\big)^m
\end{align}$$
for every $m=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Batominovski .

Answer (score 0):

To prove 1st statement, there is nothing to be do, it is given in the question,

for second statement write $sec\theta =\sqrt{1+tan^2\theta }$ and then write $1=tan^2\theta + sec^2\theta$

Comment: The biggest challange is the last statement. Pls help.

Comment: The given formula involves $m$ and $1$, so there is, in fact, *something* to do to prove the first statement, which has $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Blue, it is not my homework, rather a problem I am interested to know. Moreover, I have myself tried it several times.

Comment: @AweKumarJha: That's fine. (You could even say so in your question.) However, the community here tends to frown-upon questions that simply state a problem without providing context. Many (most?) of us have little interest in just solving posted problems (unless they're really, really interesting!); we're here to help people *understand* those problems. So, providing your own thoughts about the problem is useful. You say you've "tried several times". Show us what you've tried and we might be able to identify your errors and/or clarify your misconceptions. Help us help you!